# Error en jQuery, al enviar FORM: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, formularios

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at xb (jquerymin.js:4)
    at xb (jquerymin.js:4)
```

Hola, intento enviar el siguiente formulario, y recibo este error por consola:

```
<form id="form_comentarios" action="POST">
    <!--<input type="hidden" id="puntuacion" required>-->
    <input type="hidden" id="codigo_producto" value="<?php echo $producto['id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" style="width: 50%;" required><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="width: 50%;" required><br>
    <textarea id="comentario" placeholder="Escriba aquí su comentario" required></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Comentar">
</form>
```

Recibo los datos en un archivo .js (que pongo a continuación):

```
$("#form_comentarios").submit(function(e){
  var puntuacion = $('#puntuacion').val()
  var codigo_producto = $('#codigo_producto').val()
  var nombre = $('#nombre').val()
  var cod_agente = $('#cod_agente').val()
  var fecha = $('#fecha').val()

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/setValoracion.php',
    data: {'puntuacion': puntuacion,
           'codigo_producto': codigo_producto,
           'nombre': nombre,
           'email': email,
           'comentario': comentario,
            }
  })
  .done(function(insertarComentario){
    alert('comentario enviado con éxito');
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('fallo');
  })
});
```

Este es el PHP al que intento acceder:

```
function insertarComentario(){
    $puntuacion = $_POST['puntuacion'];
    $codigo_producto = $_POST['codigo_producto'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO comentarios (id_prod, nombre_cliente, email, comentario) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('isss', $codigo_producto, $nombre, $email, $comentario);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
}

echo insertarComentario();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que tu problema esta en que se te estan pasando algunos datos como por ejemplo en tu archivo js no veo en ningun lado que recives el comentario y luego lo envias en el data sin estar definido, tambien me pregunto por que el input tipo hidden esta comentado y lo estas reciviendo en archivo **js** y **php** ,tambien en el data el comentario tiene una coma al final por lo que el **ajax** se queda esperando por mas parametros por enviar.

entonces te propongo esta modificacion...

```
 <form id="form_comentarios" action="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="puntuacion" required>
    <input type="hidden" id="codigo_producto" value="<?php echo $producto['id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" style="width: 50%;" required><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="width: 50%;" required><br>
    <textarea id="comentario" placeholder="Escriba aquí su comentario" required></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Comentar">
</form>
```

archivo **js** modificado

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form_comentarios").submit(function(e){
      var puntuacion = $('#puntuacion').val()
      var codigo_producto = $('#codigo_producto').val()
      var nombre = $('#nombre').val()
      var cod_agente = $('#cod_agente').val()
      var comentario = $('#comentario').val()
      var fecha = $('#fecha').val()

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/setValoracion.php',
        data: {'puntuacion': puntuacion,
               'codigo_producto': codigo_producto,
               'nombre': nombre,
               'email': email,
               'comentario': comentario
                }
      })
      .done(function(response){
     if(response=="ok"){
        alert('comentario enviado con éxito');
       }else{

           alert('comentario fallo');
      }
      })
      .fail(function(){
        alert('fallo');
      })
    });
})
```

archivo **php** modificado

```
 $puntuacion = $_POST['puntuacion'];
    $codigo_producto = $_POST['codigo_producto'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO comentarios (id_prod, nombre_cliente, email, comentario) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('isss', $codigo_producto, $nombre, $email, $comentario);
   if( $stmt->execute()){
     echo "ok";
    $stmt->close();

}else{
 echo "fail";
}
$con->close();
```

ojala y sea de tu ayuda saludos!

Comment: Me sale, comentario fallo, con lo que el response no me da como ok, no entiendo porque lo metes a un echo, ¿Habría que conservar ese código en la función que tenia?

Comment: Sin embargo, si inserta el comentario..

Comment: antes no lo insertaba?

Comment: No, pero ya lo he solucionado!!! Tu respuesta me ha servido !!

Comment: que bueno que te sirviera saludos!